# How can I know the exact column name and value on which the conversion failed while running an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got below error while running a SQL query:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I tried putting it Line by Line so that the error would point out the exact line and it did.
But to my surprise a date / time conversion error was given and pointed to a field which is varchar. In this example it pointed out to 'F1' as Facility field which is the first line of the query.

```
SELECT       'F1' AS FACILITY, NULL AS NSH, NULL AS EMC, NULL AS OD, NULL AS OA, 
             URN AS PA, 
             Title, [First Name], [Second Name], [Third Name], [Family Name], Sex, [Date Of Birth], 
             [Estimated Date Of Birth ], [Marital Status], 
             Religion, [Nationality Code], 
                         Nationality, [Passport  Number], [Country Of Birth], [Preferred Language],  
                         Address, [PO Box], CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), [Home Phone]) AS [Home Phone], [Office Phone], [Mobile Phone], [Blood Type], VIP, Notes, [National ID], NULL AS [Deceased Date], NULL AS [Deceased Time], 
                        NULL AS [Deceased Indicator (Y/N)], NULL AS [Location Of Death], NULL AS [Death Notified By]
FROM         PD_PA
UNION ALL
SELECT       'F2' AS FACILITY, URN AS NSH, NULL AS EMC, NULL AS OD, NULL AS OA, NULL AS PA, Title, [First Name], [Second Name], [Third Name], [Family Name], Sex, BDATE AS [Date Of Birth], [Estimated Date Of Birth], [Marital Status], Religion, [NationalityCode], 
                         Nationality, [Passport  Number], [Country], [Preferred Language], 
                         Address, [PO Box], CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), [Home Phone]) AS [Home Phone], [Office Phone], [Mobile Phone] AS [MobilePhone], [Blood Type], VIP, Notes, [National ID], NULL AS [Deceased Date], NULL AS [Deceased Time], 
                         NULL AS [Deceased Indicator (Y/N)], NULL AS [Location Of Death], NULL AS [Death Notified By]
FROM         PD_LKIL
```

Is there a way to trace or know the details of which is the exact field and on which value exactly is the error thrown?

Since my data has over 100k entries, its difficult to trace out and proceed.

Comment: Remove one field at a time until the error goes away.

Comment: (part of) the reason it doesn't do this automatically is because it stops on encountering the first error. There could easily be *multiple* errors within the data and it doesn't make (much) sense to single out one. Since there are no obvious casts to `date` related types in the query itself, it suggests a mismatch in the column definitions - it shouldn't take too long to find where one table declares a `datetime` column and the other has `varchar`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever .. Yes I agree that it stops on encountering the first error. Thats the reason I ask whether is there some place where we can see a detailed report of where it stopped - Value and Field/Column Name

Comment: Thanks Microsoft for allowing this common error to persist for oh, what, 20 years now?  Please update the error message to contain at least the column name in question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a version  greater than  2008 you can replace your CONVERT with `TRY_CONVERT`.

This returns null if the conversion fails so you can simply check for NULLs in the output.